# C++ Letters -> Numbers

Tags: c++

**This is my first time posting a question to Stack Overflow. I am new at programming so please excuse me if I say things strange or wrong.** In the file below; it reads the directory and saves it to a variable nAddress. It then removes the file extension; breaks up the file into 700 lines each rebuilds the extension; and lastly, increments the filename by 1 letter IE: testA, testB, testC, testD, etc.

**Reworded:**
Current Output:

Test is 1400 lines so it outputs

TestA

TestB

IT NEEDS TO BE:

Test1

Test2

Could you point me in the right direction? Thanks!

```
string fAddress = argv[1];

if (argc > 2)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++)
    {
        string temp = argv[i];
        fAddress = fAddress + " " + temp;
    }
}
cout << fAddress << "\n" <<endl;

// Convert to a char*
const size_t newsize = 500;
char nstring[newsize];
strcpy_s(nstring, fAddress.c_str());
strcat_s(nstring, "");


// Convert to a wchar_t*
size_t origsize = strlen(fAddress.c_str()) + 1;
size_t convertedChars = 0;
wchar_t wcstring[newsize];
mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcstring, origsize, fAddress.c_str(), _TRUNCATE);
wcscat_s(wcstring, L"");


ifstream inFile;
inFile.open (wcstring);
int index = 0;

string parts[100];
string text;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   parts[i] = "";

}

// get info until ; is found in each line and add it to the array of char*
while ( !inFile.eof( ) )
{
   getline(inFile, text, (char)1);
  if ( !inFile )
  {
      if (inFile.eof( ) )
         break;
      else
      {
         cout << "File error...\n";
         break;
         system("PAUSE");
     }
  }

    parts[index] += text;
    index++;
}
inFile.close();
int n = fAddress.length(); // Get the total size of the file name. 

string nAddress =     "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++";
cout<<"Removing previous file extension...\n";
n = n - 4; //Remove the extension from the output file
cout<<"Removed previous file extension successfully...\n\n";
cout<< "Building file location and name....\n";
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   nAddress[i] = nstring[i]; //nstring hold the name

}
 cout<< "Built successfully....\n\n";
//Now nAddress is equal to the location and name of the file....



nAddress[n] = '0' ;//'A';

cout<<nAddress[n];

 // nAddress[n+1] = 1+48;
 //system("cls");
 cout<< "Building file extension...\n"<< endl;
 for (int i = n; i < n+4; i++) // n is whatever the length of the string is. Add 4 chars onto the n.
 {
   nAddress[i+1] = nstring[i];
   fileextension = fileextension + nstring[i]; //This saves off the full file extension for later use. :)

   //cout <<nAddress;   This seems to build the extension of the file... IE .T, .TA, .TAP

  }
  cout<< "File extension built successfully...\n"<< endl;
  nAddress[n+5] = '\0';
  //cout<< nAddress;
  string files[10];

//This is the part that searches through the file and splits it up I believe.
for (int i = 0; i < index-2; i++)
{
   files[i] = parts[0] + parts[i+1] + parts[index-1];
    //cout<< files[i]; //This line will output the entire file in the CMD window
}
//system("cls");
// The function below is where the names are dished out
nAddress[n-20];
int counter = 0;
int lastnum;
for (int i = 0; i < index-2; i++)
{
    //string myval;
    //ostringstream convert;
    //counter++;
    //convert << counter ;


    nAddress[n] = i + 65;   //this is the line that gives the letters... it comes in with an A as the first file FYI
    //nAddress = nAddress + convert.str();
    //cout<<convert.str();
    //cout<<counter;

    //myval = nAddress[n];
    //cout<<myval;


    cout<<"Outputting sub-files...\n" <<endl;
    cout<<nAddress<< "\n" << endl;

    size_t origsize = strlen(nAddress.c_str()) + 1;
    size_t convertedChars = 0;
    wchar_t wcstrings[newsize];
    mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcstrings, origsize, nAddress.c_str(), _TRUNCATE);
    wcscat_s(wcstrings, L"");


    ofstream outFile (wcstrings);   
    outFile << files[i];
}
```

Comment: This line nAddress[n-20]; does nothing.  Was it a typo?  Also, please compile with warnings enabled and fix them to help the rest of your code be happier.

Comment: You're right. I haven't been cleaning up when I mess with things. There are several lines commented out that I've been playing with.

Comment: @user2506739 Anything helped? Do you have an acceptable answer?

Answer (score 3):

Use s.th. like this:

```
std::string getPartFilename(int partNumber)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;

    oss << "Test" << partNumber;
    return oss.str();
}
```

**UPDATE**
To clarify my point: Refactor your code to remove all those pesky c string operations (`strcpy_s()` , `strcat_s()`, etc.) for building the file names, and use a simple straightforward C++ standard mechanism to format the strings as you need them.

Answer (score 2):

okay, so if

```
nAddress[n] = i + 65;
```

is truly where the incremented letter of the file gets set, than here's what I'd do.

since you're using std:string,

```
// make your address just "test"
nAddress[n] = '\0';

// cast `i` to a string and concatinate
nAddress += to_string(i);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/

---

If you weren't using std:string you'd approach it like this

```
// make your address just "test"
nAddress[n] = '\0';  

// make a character array that contains the character representation of `i`
char buffer[50];
sprintf("%d", i);

// concatinate
strcat(nAddress, buffer);
```

or, you can merely do

```
sprintf(&nAddress[n], "%d", i);
```

as indiv mentioned

---

Comment: And of course, this solution is the one he will want to turn to next week when the professor asks him to handle a wider variety of input...

Comment: Did I miss the [tag:c] tag on the question?

Comment: @user2506739 I've edited my answer to take advantage of the `std:string` library that you're using.  The solution should be much simpler now

Comment: Thank you for providing the references as well.

Answer (score 0):

To change the letter to a number (if I understand the code correct),

`nAddress[n] = i + 65;`

should become

`nAddress[n] = i + '0';`

Comment: That did it. Wow. I've been trying everything. Thank you!

Comment: How far works this for values of `i`?? Insert 11 for `i`, what will be displayed? Hmmm, even didn't have a deeper look. Maybe this clumsy code works that way ...

Comment: Agreed it is clumsy and won't work past 9, but his code wouldn't work to higher numbers anyways so I gave him the simplest path.  My guess is that nAddress[n] already was limited in how high it could print anyways so that this homework assignment would work.

Comment: I seem to remember him explicitly stating in the question that he needed it to be a number so that he could have **MORE** than 26 filenames

Comment: It's actually not homework. I don't start school till the fall; but I'm jumping into a friends code to see what I can come up with and I was extremely lost on that part. You are right; it doesn't output above 9 which isn't going to work either. I had to make a bigger file to test that.

Comment: @user2506739 and as you can see, the reason why you need this done is actually quite significant.  you might want to edit that back into your question.

Comment: If it requires numbers greater than 9, this will break down and you will need to use a sprintf() solution like @SamIAm has shown above.  BTW, no need to downvote this, it solved the problem as stated guys and I already upvoted the better answer.  Just leave it as a small scope answer...

Comment: I didn't realize I had marked this question as important. I didn't even see a checkbox for that.... I will do a google search on that I suppose and see how to mark it as "normal". Thank you for letting me know. :)